# Using Perl bind_param with SQL IN statement

Tags: sql, perl, dbi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there SQL parameter binding for arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513818/is-there-sql-parameter-binding-for-arrays)

I was wondering if there is anyway to use bind_param with SQL IN statements. According to perl documentation bind_param_array cannot be used as well. Has anyone come across the same situation?

http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI#bind_param_array

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No you can't do this easily. One option is to use `$dbh->quote`, eg.

```
my @values = (1,2,3,4);
my $sql = "SELECT * from my_table WHERE ID IN (";
$sql .= join(',', map { $dbh->quote($_) } @values)
$sql .= ')';
```

Or you can create the necessary placeholders and pass the array in as bind parameters, eg.

```
my @values = (1,2,3,4);
my $sql = "SELECT * from my_table WHERE ID IN (";
$sql .= join(',', map { '?' } @values);
$sql .= ')';

my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(@values);
```

Neither is exceptionally pretty.

Answer (score 1):

Not if you're wanting an arbitrary number of placeholders, no.  You can use it with an IN, as in

```
where foo in ( ?, ?, ? )
```

but then you must have exactly three binds.